# POP3 connect closed without indication

Tags: java, ssl, jakarta-mail, pop3

I'm trying to read messages using POP, but there is a problem. Here  `client.connect("pop.gmail.com",995);` there is always an error `java.io.EOFException: Connection closed without indication.` I don't know, why it doesn't want to connect/

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3s"); 
        props.put("mail.pop3.auth", "false");
        props.put("mail.pop3.ssl.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.pop3.ssl.trust", "*");
        props.put("mail.pop3.ssl.trust", "pop.gmail.com");
        client = new POP3Client();
        client.connect("pop.gmail.com",995);
```

Could you please help me! Thank u.

Comment: It's been a while, but doesn't one need a socket factory for the SSL?

Comment: No, you definitely [do not need a socket factory](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).

Comment: The JavaMail FAQ has [code for connecting to Gmail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#gmail).  You should be sure you understand the difference between POP and IMAP before choosing to use POP.